# Turn off webapp dyno using api - Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, request

I am trying to make a script that checks to see if my dyno is idle, if it is then it stops the dyno/webapp. The only problem is that it seems to do nothing even though the post request will come back with accepted:

```
from email import header
import requests
import dotenv

heroku_api_token = "Bearer ENTERAPITOKENHERE"
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
    'Authorization': heroku_api_token
}
statecheck = requests.get("https://api.heroku.com/apps/rockosmodernapp/dynos/web.1",headers=headers).json()
print(statecheck)
if statecheck["state"] == "idle":
    print("shutting down web app worker")
elif statecheck["state"] == "up":
    print("app is still up, will check in 15 minutes to see if app is idle")

postheader = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
    'Authorization': heroku_api_token
}
stopdynoobject = {

}

stopdyno = requests.post("https://api.heroku.com/apps/rockosmodernapp/dynos/web.1/actions/stop",headers=postheader)
print(stopdyno.reason)
```

It will look like it will stop, then it just immediately restarts:

```
2022-10-20T03:05:55.221896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-10-20T03:05:56.368472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-10-20T03:05:56.673413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-10-20T03:06:13.858381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
```

Also the dashboard still shows the web worker running:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - Use the FORMATION endpoint from Heroku's api to change the quantity of web workers to 0. This will turn off the dyno in heroku, thus saving money.

```
from email import header
import requests
import json
import dotenv

heroku_api_token = "Bearer ENTERHEROKUAPIKEYHERE"
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
    'Authorization': heroku_api_token
}
statecheck = requests.get("https://api.heroku.com/apps/rockosmodernapp/dynos/web.1",headers=headers).json()
print(statecheck)
if statecheck["state"] == "idle":
    print("shutting down web app worker")
elif statecheck["state"] == "up":
    print("app is still up, will check in 15 minutes to see if app is idle")

postheader = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
    'Authorization': heroku_api_token
}

stopdynoobject = {
    "updates" :[{"quantity":0,
                "type": "web"}]
}

stopdynoobject_str = json.dumps(stopdynoobject)
turnoffdyno = requests.patch("https://api.heroku.com/apps/rockosmodernapp/formation",headers=headers,data=stopdynoobject_str).json()
print(turnoffdyno)
```